# How to update multiple tables in MS Access from multiple excel files?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Every month I have to UPDATE my MS Access db from approximately 30 excel files. They have all the same structure and format. I try to modify this code several times to update each tables in my db in once but i didn't succeed. (found in this forum)

I have 3 questions:
How is it possible to say to the vba code to look at this range in the excel template which correspond to this column in the MS Access db?

How can i make this vba code update all the tables in once based on the Primary Key?

Then, Is it possible to select the Folder where all these excel files are and the code will loop through all files?

```
Public Sub UpdatePriceList()
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sProduct As String, sVariety As String, cPrice As Variant
' connect to the Access database
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
    "Data Source=C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\Database1.accdb;"
' open a recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "PriceList", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable

Range("A2").Activate  ' row 1 contains column headings
Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    sProduct = ActiveCell.Value
    sVariety = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    cPrice = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value

    rs.Filter = "product='" & sProduct & "' AND variety='" & sVariety & "'"
    If rs.EOF Then
        Debug.Print "No existing record - adding new..."
        rs.Filter = ""
        rs.AddNew
        rs("product").Value = sProduct
        rs("variety").Value = sVariety
    Else
        Debug.Print "Existing record found..."
    End If
    rs("price").Value = cPrice
    rs.Update
    Debug.Print "...record update complete."

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate  ' next cell down
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: I think that this question would be better on StackOverflow - it appears to more about programming than databases per se. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to deal with a single excel file and convert it to acess table and all the rest of file will be treated the same way. You can use a bot which will automate the task and do  it quickfast. You just have to give it the "instruction" how to deal with single file and it will do the rest.

The instruction can be as simple as a notepad file with table containing the mouse positions and the stroken keyboards key necessary to deal with one file.

You may use "Autoit V3 script"